# Class label doesn't work in vue component. This is bulma framework

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bulma

This is code from bulma.io and I try using it in template of the component file(.vue)

```
<div class="field">
      <label class="label">Name</label>
         <div class="control">
             <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input">
        </div>
    </div>
```

But content label tag (word "Name") doesn't appear in browser. If I delete class='label' then it does. Why it happens?

Comment: what is the css for `.label`?

Comment: there may be some conflicts in your css.